# Probability of having two cycles of length n/2 in an Erdős-Rényi graph?

Tags: probability, random-graphs

Given an Erdős-Rényi graph $\mathbb{G}(n,p)$ (that is, a random graph where each edge exists with probability $p$), what is the probability of having that a graph created according to $\mathbb{G}(n,p)$ contains exactly two cycles
of length $n/2$ and no other edges (assume that $n$ is even for this)?

Comment: What have you tried? Can you figure it out for small values of $n$?

Comment: I drew two graphs of 6 and 8 nodes, in each I figured out we need to have n+1 edges in order to have exactly 2 cycles, and thus I assume the probability will be the same as in the definition of Erdős-Rényi graph in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erd%C5%91s%E2%80%93R%C3%A9nyi_model, with number of edges n+1

Comment: We need $n$ edges, and they need to be connected in a specific way to get two cycles. So you need to count how many ways there are of doing that.

Comment: Yes after rechecking I figured it must be $n$ edges.